# stretch a div to match it to the sum of width of 2 divs below it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make 3 divs align in such a way that the top div stretches to make the sum of the width of the bottom 2 divs. 
 [Attached Image of the expected div positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqVMn.jpg) 
 I tried using display : table-row for the divs.

```
<div id="main_div" style="display: table-row">
        <div id='col1' style="width: 300px; display: table-cell;">
            <div style="display: table-row">
                <div  style="width: 300px; display: table-cell;text-align :right;border-style: groove;">
                    <h1>This is heading 1</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: table-row">            
                <div  style="width: 150px; display: table-cell;white-space: nowrap;border-style: groove; border-color: green;">
                    abc: <input type="text" name="def">
                </div>
                <div  style="width: 150px; display: table-cell;white-space: nowrap;border-style: groove; border-color: red">
                    def: <input type="text" name="ghi">
                </div>                                                      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably you are looking for something like a colspan = 2

Comment: Check the updated answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

You can also achieve this by `div` elements by using the `float: left` and `display: inline-block` property of css.

```css
.row:before,.row:after{
  content:"";
  display:table;
}
.row:after{
  clear:both;
}
.row{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
}
.full{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.half{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-top:1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.half:last-of-type{
  border-right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="full">
    DIV 1
  </div>
  <div class="half">
    DIV2
  </div>
  <div class="half">
    DIV3
  </div>
</div>
```

The best way to achieve this layout is to use `table`. Please check the code below:

```css
table{
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
td{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">DIV 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DIV 2</td>
      <td>DIV 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have it currently as table. trying to change it to a div, for other reasons.

Comment: That's awesome ! Looks just like the way I want . Thanks

Comment: Thanks again! sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Using flex from css3:

```html
<div style="width: 300px;">
    <div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">Hello</div>
    <div style="width: 302px; display: flex;">
        <div style="width: 50%;  border: 1px solid black;">1</div>
        <div style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid black;">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The 302px width is the left and right 1px borders